# Delete cookie on first of each month

Tags: jquery, html, js-cookie

Is it possible to delete a cookie on the first of each month, rather than waiting for the cookie to manually expire? This is so that I can display a message to a user once per month, regardless of how many times they view the site. I am using js-cookie.

Comment: You can set cookies to expire after a month, regardless of how many times the website is viewed. You just have to get your code that creates the cookie to check if there is a cookie already there before running it. So 'if the cookie does not exist, create cookie'. Otherwise you will overwrite the cookie each time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The code below sets the current year and month as a cookie value e.g. 20173 for March 2017. On subsequent visits, it then checks the cookie value against the current date and if the current date is higher, it deletes the previous cookie and creates a new one with the current date. So, on the 1st of April, strDate will be 20174 which is higher than 20173 so the previous cookie is deleted and set as the new date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var d = new Date();
     var strYear = d.getFullYear() // cur year 
     var strMonth = d.getMonth()+1 // cur month
     var strDate = ("" + strYear + strMonth) // year + month e.g. 20173

     if (Cookies.get('cookieName') == null) { // cookie doesn't exist
        Cookies.set('cookieName', strDate, { expires: 40 }) // create cookie
        $('#modal').modal('show'); // show modal
     }
     else if (Cookies.get('cookieName') < strDate) { // cookie is older than 1 month
          Cookies.remove('cookieName'); // remove cookie to reset it
          Cookies.set('cookieName', strDate, { expires: 40 }) // create cookie
          $('#modal').modal('show'); // show modal
     }
     else {

     }
  });
```